# How do I add exception handling to this part of my code?

Tags: java, exception

I have two problems. First, I have created an exception handling in this first part of my code, the try again concept.

```
do {
    try {
        if(exitType.length()==1){
            char exitChar = exitType.charAt(0);
            exit = exitChar;
            if (exit == 'Y' || exit == 'y' || exit == 'N' || exit == 'n') {
                x = 1; 
            } else {
                throw new StringException("Invalid letter...\n");
            }
        } else {
            throw new StringException("Invalid input a string...\n");
        } 
    } catch(StringException i) {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("You typed: " + exitType + i);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Try again? (y/n): ");
        exitType = input.next();
        x = 0;
    }
```

The output when the user enters a letter besides y/n, would be:

```
Try again? (y/n): w
-------------------------------------------
You typed: wStringException: Invalid letter...
-------------------------------------------
```

First question: How do I put the StringException: Invalid letter... on the next line so it's not beside the 'w' (just for clarity and neatness of output). Hope you get me.

By the way, I have created my own exception:

```
public class StringException extends Exception {
    public StringException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }   
}
```

Second, I cannot figure out how to add exception handling in this part where the user is asked to enter the letter of choice:

```
public static void operation() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choiceString = "";
    char choice = 'a';
    System.out.print("Enter letter of choice: ");
    choiceString = input.next();
    if (choiceString.length() == 1) {
        choice = choiceString.charAt(0);
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");

        switch(choice) {
            case 'a': {
                try {
                    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
                    double width = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
                    double height = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("What is the color of the shape? ");
                    String color = input.next();
                    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
                    Shape cia;
                    Shape rec = new Rectangle(color, width, height);
                    cia = rec;
                    System.out.println(rec);
                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(color, width, height);
                    r.print();
                } catch(InputMismatchException i) {
                    System.out.println("InputMismatchException caught");
                }
                break;  
            }
            case 'b': {
            //**** 
            }
            case 'c': {
            //****
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid choice...");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input...");
    }
```

I only need to know where I should place the try-catch block only on the part where it prompts about the letter of choice.

Comment: Please add a tag to your question to specify the programming language. That will help you to attract the attention of people who can help.

Comment: You shouldn't use exception as a control flow statement. Catch the error, and use if and while statements to control the program flow.

Comment: Don't change your question like that. If you have a new question you can post it separately. An objetive of the site is to generate information not just for you but for future searches by other people.

Answer (score 0):

> First question: How do I put the StringException: Invalid letter... on
>   the next line so it's not beside the 'w'

Change

```
System.out.println("You typed: " + exitType);
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println(i);
```

to

```
System.out.println("You typed: " + exitType + i);
```

`println` adds a newline after printing what is in the argument (which is different from `print`)

> Second, I cannot figure out how to add exception handling in this part
>   where the user is asked to enter the letter of choice:

You can add it in the `default` case or, better, in the `else`

```
else {
        throw new ...
    }
```

Comment: Your answer to the first question is wrong. `exitType` is the "w", and `i` is the exception text.

Answer (score 0):

First question: in your catch you have

```
System.out.print("You typed: " + exitType + i);
```

just change to

```
System.out.print("You typed: " + exitType + "\n" + i);
```

`\n` is an [escaping code](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/character-escape-codes-in-java.html) which acts as a new line. For sake of completeness, you should actually use `\n\r` for system compatibility

I didn't really get the second question, isn't it enough if you place your `try/catch` around `choiceString = input.next();`? It also depends how you want to manage the exception after you catch it.

Comment: There is another way to get line separator: `System.getProperty("line.separator")`